# What is SDLC tag?

Tags: support, tags

Today I noticed [sdlc](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdlc) tag, which has no information written.

Anyone know what exactly is it?

[List of questions with this tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdlc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The acronym stands for [Systems (or Software) Development Life Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life-cycle).

Comment: thanks. that makes sense