# Tag merge / synonym request: [life-cycle] → [sdlc]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [life-cycle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life-cycle) (22 questions) into [sdlc](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdlc) (35), and make them synonyms.

Only [sdlc](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdlc) tag has wiki, but questions in both appear to be about [software development lifecycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process).

---

Preference for master tag is because it is less ambiguous (life-cycle appears to be sometimes (mis)used for questions of Life, the Universe, and Everything).

Related: [What is SDLC tag?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5946/what-is-sdlc-tag)